# Fastest method for testing a fixed phone number pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, underscore.js, lodash

So, the challenge is that we are trying to detect if a string matches a fixed phone number pattern, this is a simple string pattern.

The pattern is:

```
ddd-ddd-dddd
```

Where "d "represents a decimal digit and the minus symbol represents itself, "-"

The patterns that are currently used for testing are, but can be increased if it is felt that there are not enough patterns to debunk an incorrect format.

```
"012-345-6789"
"0124-345-6789"
"012-3456-6789"
"012-345-67890"
"01a-345-6789"
"012-34B-6789"
"012-345-678C"
"012"
```

**The goal , the answer that I seek, is to find the method that executes the fastest to return a `boolean` where `true` means that the pattern is good and `false` means that the pattern is bad.**

Here is my current solution

```
function matchesPattern(pattern) {
    if (pattern.length !== 12) {
        return false;
    }

    var i = 0,
        code;

    while (i < 12) {
        code = pattern.charCodeAt(i);

        if (i > 8 || i % 4 !== 3) {
            if (code < 48 || code > 57) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (code !== 45) {
            return false;
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It is available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/WA88n/) along with the test patterns

I have a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/fastest-method-for-testing-a-fixed-phone-number-pattern/8) created where I will add further suggested method so that the execution speeds of the methods can be compared to determine which is fastest

Your method can be any valid javascript code that will execute in the a browser, you can use ECMA5 and target modern browsers if you so wish, or use cross-browser standards, the answer will not be deemed incorrect if it does not run on IE6 for example. You may also use any 3rd party libraries that you wish, i.e. jquery, lodash, underscore, etc etc. The final requirement is that the code must not fail to execute on Chrome v25 or Firefox v20

I anything is unclear then please feel free to leave a comment and I will update my question to clarify.

Answers that differ by only micro-optimisations count

Please don't change your answer if it working and has been added to the performance chart. You can submit more than 1 answer.

Update: Ok a week has passed and now it is time to announce the answer that I will choose.

What has been learnt from this exercise?

It would seem that regexs are comparatively slow, although fast enough for most tasks, when compared to a hand built javascript routine. (at least for small string patterns)

There was no solution using any 3rd party library, jquery, undescore etc, nothing. Not so much of a surprise, but I though that someone may have tried.

Unrolled loops still appear to be king. Many say that it is not necessary these days as the browsers are so advanced, but this test still showed them to be king of the pile.

I'd like to thank all those that engaged in this question, and especially to those that actually submitted code for testing.

Comment: What do I get if I win?

Comment: 1? I don't even get out of bed for less than 100 rep. (Seriously though, did you not even _try_ a regex solution of your own before posting here?)

Comment: Seriously yes. You will also gain through any up-voting of your answer

Comment: Not loving the format of this "question".

Comment: @AD7six Is there something that needs clarifying or have you a suggestion for improving the "format"?

Comment: @Xotic750 ask a question without changing how SO works to be a competition. infact -1. primarily for all these "Your answer appears to give correct results and has been entered into the performance test." comments.

Comment: @AD7six Why not? He is asking for the, in fact, fastest method, and there has to be a comparison to determine it. It just encourages creative ideas.

Comment: @AD7six Something wrong with letting a person that is reading the questions and answers know that the OP has tested it and updated the information? the question is a serious one, and does not set out to make SO look like a competition site.

Comment: @Xotic750 can you remove 'Control' cause its everytime the fastest and it wont show the winner

Comment: Sure thing, I don't think it is required any longer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even faster than before:

```
function tecjam5(pattern) {
    var c;
    return !(pattern.length != 12 ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(2))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(4))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(11))>>1) == 28 || (c>>3) == 6) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(0))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(1))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(5))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(6))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(8))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(9))>>3) == 6 || (c>>1) == 28) ||
    !(((c=pattern.charCodeAt(10))>>1) == 28 || (c>>3) == 6) ||
    pattern.charAt(3) != '-' || pattern.charAt(7) != '-');
}
```

(short: every number < 8 only need compared once)

Comment: You answer appears to give correct results and has been entered into the performance test

Answer (score 3):

```
function whyNotBeSilly(pattern) {
  return !(pattern.length !== 12 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(0)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(1)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(2)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(4)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(5)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(6)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(8)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(9)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(10)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           (code = pattern.charCodeAt(11)) < 48 || code > 57 ||
           pattern.charAt(3) != '-' || pattern.charAt(7) != '-');
}
```

Comment: Your answer appears to give correct results and has been entered into the performance test.

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex for that:

```
if(/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/.test('123-456-7890'))
    //ok
else
    //not ok
```

Comment: As you have the begin "^" and end identifiers "$", you do no need the global "g" flag as we are not searching within the string but matching the whole thing

Comment: Wouldn't `.test()` be a better method than `.exec()` if you just want a pass/fail result? A one-line function with `return /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(pattern);` should work...

Comment: You answer appears to give correct results and has been entered into the performance test.

Comment: @nnnnnn, will you be submitting that as an answer, rather than a comment?

Comment: Nope. It's just a tidier (in my opinion) version of this answer. No need to double up.

Comment: Shame, it has been added but of course it could be claimed by someone else.

Comment: It may take a lot of help from my therapist, but eventually I'll deal with it if somebody claims "my" work. More seriously, regarding the `for` loops in the performance tests, aren't they all exiting on the first iteration given they all have a `return` statement inside the loop? So all four methods currently included are only really testing the first phone number...

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah I saw that when I added anoter solution which was benchmarked faster than 'control'.

Comment: @nnnnnn They are testing all the characters in the first test case. Why would you continue to test characters in the other test cases if you discover that the pattern sequence is incorrect? What is the point you are making, all the answers follow the rules.

Comment: No, I'm saying that by using a return statement inside the for loop you are testing only the first phone number, "012-345-6789". The other phone numbers don't get tested.

Comment: @Xotic750 the problem with the testcases was, that the loops were exited by return after first loop (see my revision)

Comment: Ah yes, ok. +1 for the catch

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation of one of the other answers, but I believe the built-in character class should be slightly faster than a custom one:

```
return /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: Your answer appears to give correct results and has been entered into the performance test.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a regex object pre-compiles it for any future use. Since you are looping through several test strings, it should perform better to instantiate the object outside the function first:

```
var rex = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
```

Then the function would be:

```
function matchesPattern(pattern) {
    return rex.test(pattern);
}
```

Comment: Your answer appears to give correct results and has been entered into the performance test.

Answer (score 1):

very fast:

```
   function tecjam3(pattern) {
  if (pattern.length !== 12) {
    return false;
  }

  code = pattern.charCodeAt(0);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;
  code = pattern.charCodeAt(1);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;
  code = pattern.charCodeAt(2);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;

  code = pattern.charCodeAt(4);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;
  code = pattern.charCodeAt(5);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;
  code = pattern.charCodeAt(6);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;

  code = pattern.charCodeAt(8);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;
  code = pattern.charCodeAt(9);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;
  code = pattern.charCodeAt(10);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;
  code = pattern.charCodeAt(11);
  if (code < 48 || code > 57) return false;

  if (pattern.charAt(3) != '-' || pattern.charAt(7) != '-') return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: You answer appears to give correct results and has been entered into the performance test.