# Whats more economical RegExp that fulfill all example below:

Tags: javascript, regex

Whats more economical RegExp that fulfill all example below:

- W.12345678
- W.12345678.12,
- W.12345678.12.123
- W.12345678.12.123.12

1 char (8digits) mandatory
followed by a combination of (.) and 2,3,2 digits.

I found :-

```
^[A-Z]{1}\.\d{8}(?:\.\d{2}|\.\d{2}\.\d{3}|\.\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}|\.\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})$
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? First I assume these are strings, but are you trying to verify (test) with a regex that they are constructed correctly, or perhaps regex match the parts for some other use?

Comment: Furthermore, the 1 char, I assume capital modern latin alphabet, by your original regex?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a few improvements:

`{1}` never does anything. So drop it.

Your last two alternatives are the same. So drop the last one. That would give

```
^[A-Z]\.\d{8}(?:\.\d{2}|\.\d{2}\.\d{3}|\.\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})$
```

Finally, you could use optional parts instead of alternation, if you prefer:

```
^[A-Z]\.\d{8}(?:\.\d{2}(?:\.\d{3}(?:\.\d{2})?)?)?$
```

Whether that's more readable or not is up to you. As thg435 points out, you can save another two characters, by expanding the `{2}`

```
^[A-Z]\.\d{8}(?:\.\d\d(?:\.\d{3}(?:\.\d\d)?)?)?$
```

But I personally don't like to mix `{n}` quantifiers with written out repetitions, and the gain from it is doubtful.

Also, in regexes that already contain a lot of backslashes, I prefer single-character classes to escapes where applicable (but that's a matter of taste), so here is an alternative:

```
^[A-Z][.]\d{8}(?:[.]\d{2}(?:[.]\d{3}(?:[.]\d{2})?)?)?$
```

Comment: to compress it even further, `\d\d` is shorter than `\d{2}` ;)

Comment: @thg435 true, I only use that when I'm not mixing with other `{n}` though. But yeah again, that's a matter of taste. I might include it.

Comment: THANKS m.buettner...really prompt response... 'yeah the last one was a type while posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^[A-Z]\.\d{8}(?:\.\d\d(?:\.\d{3}(?:\.\d\d)?)?)?$
```

Comment: You forgot the second dot and the anchors!

Answer (score 0):

For any number of `.12.123.12.123....` you can use this:

```
^[A-Z]\.\d{8}(?:\.\d{2}(?:\.\d{3}\.\d{2})*(?:\.\d{3})?)?$
```

Comment: Thanks- Casimir et Hippolyte

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to creating and maintaining what can be a difficult regex, you could verify the strings with something like this.

Javascript

```
var strings = [];

strings.push("W.12345678");
strings.push("W.12345678.12");
strings.push("W.12345678.12.123");
strings.push("W.12345678.12.123.12");

function verify(string) {
    var parts = string.split("."),
        length = parts.length,
        lengths = [1, 8, 2, 3, 2],
        index = 1,
        part;

    if (length < 2 || length > 5 || (part = parts[0]).length !== lengths[0] || part.search(/[^A-Z]/) !== -1) {
        return false;
    }

    while (index < length) {
        part = parts[index];
        if (part.length !== lengths[index] || part.search(/[^\d]/) !== -1) {
            return false;
        }

        index += 1;
    }

    return true;
}

strings.forEach(function (string) {
    console.log(string, verify(string));
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/MpEJq/)

I haven't tried to optimise the above, and there is room for improvement. But to give you an idea of performance as it stands here is a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/verify-some-string) of the above vs one of the regexs.

With optimisation it is feasible to make it faster than the regex, and remove the regexs completely. See [Fastest method for testing a fixed phone number pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338714/fastest-method-for-testing-a-fixed-phone-number-pattern)