# Javascript capitalize first letter of each word in a string only if lengh > 2

Tags: javascript, regex

I looked at some questions and answers about capitalize in StackOverflow but could not find answer about my problem.

I would like to capitalize first letter of each word in a string only if word lengh > 2.

My temporary solution was:

```
var str =  str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
                return letter.toUpperCase();
            }).replace(/\b\w{1,2}\b/g, function (letter) {
                return letter.toLowerCase();
            });
```

There is a solution that can unite the two regex in one?

Comment: What should happen in edge cases like "i want to be 'titelised'"? Should the quoted word remain unchanged?

Comment: Or others such as "19th amendment" or "train19", unfortunately language is irregular.

Comment: @Xotic750 The functionality is for to format names.

Comment: Aha, that gives us a little more insight into what you were trying to achieve, of course there are still many 2 character names out there, especially Chinese, "jo", "ia", "li" are just some examples. So I assume whitespace boundries would be enough in your use case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This must do the job:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase(); } );
```

or to deal with unicode letters:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?<!\p{L})\p{L}(?=\p{L}{2})/gu, m => m.toUpperCase());
```

[EDIT]

The first above example is a little naive since it assumes that there is only letters in the string, and doesn't take account that a word boundary `\b` can match the limit between a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and a non word character or an anchor. Thus, to be more rigorous, it's better to write:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/([^a-z]|^)([a-z])(?=[a-z]{2})/g, function(_, g1, g2) {
    return g1 + g2.toUpperCase(); } );
```

If you want to do the same but this time, including the first letter of the string (whatever the number of letters after) you can use this:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/([^a-z])([a-z])(?=[a-z]{2})|^([a-z])/g, function(_, g1, g2, g3) {
    return (typeof g1 === 'undefined') ? g3.toUpperCase() : g1 + g2.toUpperCase(); } );
```

Comment: This does not consider if the word's length is > 2. :)

Comment: 1. When the input was "i love coding" your output was incorrect.

2. When the input was "h3llo yo people" your output was incorrect.

3. When the input was "yooooooo hi" your output was incorrect.

4. When the input was "letter by letter go" your output was incorrect.

5. When the input was "a b c d e f" your output was incorrect.

Comment: @KevinGranger: for 1,3,4,5: read the requirement (in the title), for 2: "h3llo" is not a word, it is a leet form of a word.

Comment: Great solution, although it does not address the scenario where a 1 or 2-character word is at the beginning of the string (for example "a song of ice and fire"). I believe this regex does it: /(\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2}))|^[a-z]/g

Comment: @GageTrader: indeed, but read the question one more time. However, to do what you speak about (if I understand well), you can use this pattern: `/(\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})|^[a-z])/g`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Right you are - I should've read the title more closely.

Comment: @GageTrader: You gave me the opportunity to edit my post. Thanks!

Comment: These solutions relying on `\b` word boundary class don't really work correctly if your string has non-ASCII letters like letters with accents that are common in many languages (for both regular words and for names of people). E.g. when running the above solution on a string containing my last name "Söderholm" the result is "söDerholm" which is incorrect.

Comment: @Haprog: Use `"söderholm".replace(/(?<!\p{L})\p{L}(?=\p{L}{2})/gu, (m) => m.toUpperCase());` and the honor of the Söderholm family will be safe!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w{3,}/g, function (l) {
    return l.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + l.slice(1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler solution which does the job.

```
const capitalize = (str) =>
  str.toLowerCase().replace(/\w{3,}/g, (match) =>
    match.replace(/\w/, (m) => m.toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a function to make it more clean

```
var capitalize1st = function(str){
    str = str || '';

    // string length must be more than 2
    if(str.length<3){
        return str;
    }

    return str[0].toUpperCase()+str.slice(1);
}

var splitWordsAndCap1st = function(str){
    str = str || '';

    var words = str.match(/\S+/g);

    for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        words[i] = capitalize1st(words[i]);
    }

    return words.join(' ');
}

splitWordsAndCap1st("I would like to capitalize first letter of each word in a string");
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked: **I would like to capitalize first letter of each word in a string only if word lengh > 2.**

Comment: I misunderstood the problem. I changed my answer, so now it solves the problem and you can edit the functions however you like.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex (just one small one to capture whitespace), you could do this

Javascript

```
function titleCaseLengthGt2(string) {
    var array = string.split(/(\s+)/),
        length = array.length,
        i = 0,
        word;

    while (i < length) {
        //array[i] = array[i].toLowerCase(); // make words lowercased first if you want
        word = array[i];
        if (word.length > 2) {
            array[i] = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    return array.join("");
}

console.log(titleCaseLengthGt2("i  want  to  be  titelised"));
```

Output

```
i  Want  to  be  Titelised
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/vT4zf/)

Comment: A word boundary is not the same as a whitespace. And regex does definitely help here :-)

Comment: Indeed, though that is the largest group, and that was why I questioned what the OP considered a "word". In any case, in this situation some form of small regex for splitting "words" and capturing non-"words" is required/makes it easier, even though language is irregular. I still like to avoid regexs where possible, and use them as a final resort (so to speak) :)

Comment: @whiteb0x I don't know, why not create some performance tests and share the results? It depends a little on what you are doing, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338714/fastest-method-for-testing-a-fixed-phone-number-pattern

Answer (score 0):

To capitalize first letter of each word in a string if word length > 2, I use for english text:

```
l_text = l_text.toLowerCase().replace(/(?=\b)([a-z])(?=[a-z]{2})/g, 
     function(g0) {return (g0.toUpperCase());});
```

Often in real life the rule "word length > 2" is not enough.

To capitalize town names in french I have to exclude some words like in this sample:

```
l_text = "Bourg-en-Bresse, NEUILLY SUR SEINE, enghien-les-bains";
l_text = l_text.toLowerCase().replace(/(?=\b)(?!(?:d|en|les|sous|sur)\b)([a-z])/g,
     function(g0) {return (g0.toUpperCase());});
```

For a more sophisticated situation, you may combine the negative lookahead assertion (?!(:|en|les|sous|sur)\b) and the positive lookahead assertion (?=[a-z]{2}).

To deal with non standard word boundary and characters out of a-z range, you may use a word boundary and characters set specific to the context:

```
/(?:^|[\s'\-])(?!(?:d|en|les|sous|sur)[\s'\-])([a-zàâéèêïôùûç])/g
```